# How can I create a slider like this website using Slider Revolution for WordPress? - amaze.com

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

How can I create a slider like this website using Slider Revolution for WordPress?

https://www.amaze.com

I am unsure how to create the following attributes:

- Animation when hover over Navigation arrows.
- Click on the Titles below changes slide
- Titles below do not show on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shape do define the area where hovering shall start the animation. Set the shapes opacity to 0. Use the action to start the layer animation. that's it.